# PDO doesnt return data from mysql to jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm working on a web application to maintain the administration of a restaurant, wich the functions such as:

- Show a list of all the orders, and the specific data from that when clicking on one
- Make or delete a order
- Maintain the finance's
- etc...

First i was used to using the `mysqli` extension, and was using functions like this (with the `return` statement):

```
function get_all_data_by_order_id($order_id) {
    $query = "SELECT customers.first_name,
                     customers.last_name,
                     customers.email_adress,
                     customers.customer_info,

                     orders.order_info,
                     orders.total_price,
                     orders.location,
                     orders.created

                     FROM customers
             INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id

             WHERE orders.id = {$order_id}";

    return $this->query($query);
}
```

And now i wanted to try it with PDO so i could use prepared statement easier.

I've got this php file:

```
try {
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=broodjes-service', 'root', 'password');
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if (!empty($_GET['order_id'])) {
        $order_id = $_GET['order_id'];

        $query = "SELECT customers.first_name,
                         customers.last_name,
                         customers.email_adress,
                         customers.customer_info,

                         orders.order_info,
                         orders.total_price,
                         orders.location,
                         orders.created

                         FROM customers

                 INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id

                 WHERE orders.id = :order_id";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindParam(":order_id", $order_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();
        $order_data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $orderObject = array();
        $orderObject['header'] = mysqli_fetch_array($order_data);

        echo json_encode($orderObject);

        $connection = null;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Wich is getting called by this piece of javascript to make it look like the page is'nt reloading:

```
function select_order(order) {
    var item = $(order);
    if (!item.hasClass("selectedRow")) {
        if (!selectedOrderInformation.is(":visible")) {
            switchScreen(selectedOrderInformation, financeOverview);
        }
        item.parent().find(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");
        item.addClass("selectedRow");
        selectedOrderInformation.html("loading......");
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/functions/select-order.php",
            type: "get",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {order_id: item.attr("data-order-index")},
            success: function (data) {
                selectedOrderInformation.html('<h3>' + data['header']['first_name'] + '</h3>');                }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("DEBUG: Row is already selected");
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When i try to select a order inside the list theyre in, nothing is happening. The screen stays on the 'loading...' screen. It seems like it is'nt even executing the query.

**Question**

How can i make it so that my javascript file actually reacts on the php file by deploying data from the mysql database?

Comment: DId you got any errors inside the console window?

Comment: @VikasArora Nope. Not that i have noticed, i'm logging them though.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with PDO and `mysqli_fetch_array` those do not mix together; be consistent.

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump $order_data in the PHP page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Don't mix PDO and MySQLi

Since you only want to select one row, use [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) or [`fetchAll()[0]`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Recommended way:

```
$statement->execute();
$orderObject = array();
$orderObject['header'] = $statement->fetch();   //or: $statement->fetchAll()[0]
echo json_encode($orderObject);
```

Comment: but at the first place, i was using JSON aswell, but with another way of getting the data. So how does it come i have to do that now? EDIT: This doesnt work, sorry.

Comment: By specifying `dataType: 'json',` you cause jQuery to ignore the content type of the response and parse it as JSON. Running the results through `parseJSON` will stringify the object, try to parse the results as JSON, and throw an error.

Comment: Ok, deleted it, found the important mistake

Comment: @Bluedayz But i'm not using that `mysqli` function anymore, that's just there to show that i was using it before

Comment: @Bas *"I've got this php file:"* - it contains `mysqli_fetch_array` if it's not part of your actual code, remove it from your question and post the code you are in fact using. It's just confusing for everyone.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oo like that... Didnt know that i couldnt use the mysqli_fetch_array function, yeah. then this answer does the job. thank you :)

Comment: @Bas You're welcome. It's in [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593541/pdo-doesnt-return-data-from-mysql-to-jquery-ajax#comment39976983_25593541) under your question ;)

Comment: I ment that the function with the $this->query method is not being used.

Comment: `$statement->fetch();` will return a single row. Use ` $statement->fetchAll(); `

Comment: He searches for only one row. That would work with `$statement->fetchAll()[0]` aswell, yes.

Comment: @Richie Yeah i only require one row, but thank you though.