# ajax success not getting php records

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to get my db rows from php. Currently the js success function isn't being reached. Is there anything obvious in the php that may be causing an issue?

The php

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM brand_members WHERE Id = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

The js

```
$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'dead.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "id=8",                      
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
        alert("a");         //get name
      }
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` inside your `success` function to see what exactly is the structure of your `data` variable.

Comment: did you successfully connect to your database? before running that query

Comment: console.log does not show and yes db connects ok

Comment: can you view your network response like this
https://gyazo.com/cad3c8bddc33b05c1d856d796532a32d

Comment: the data you're trying to send isn't JSON

Comment: you got `FETCH_ASSOC` activated, so your data will be something like `data[0]['id']` and `data[0]['name']` and not only `data[0]`! What does `console.log(data);` really show?

Comment: @Fred-ii- why not? `$result` is an array according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: [How to pass mysql result as jSON via ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072794/how-to-pass-mysql-result-as-json-via-ajax) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593541/pdo-doesnt-return-data-from-mysql-to-jquery-ajax

Comment: `data: "id=8"` might by the/one mistake: shouldn't it be `data: { "id": 8 }`?

Comment: @Jeff didn't I already say that? lol ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah, ok, sorry. I've read it the other way round... (as "the data from php back to client")

Comment: ok console log is returning 
[{"Id":"8","email":"test@gmail.com"}]

Comment: the console log returns my entire html page before [{"Id":"8","email":"test@gmail.com"}] which is why there is an issue. How can I just get the array

Comment: as we don't see the rest of the php-script it's hard to tell! But asccording to your description it seems that you might want to seperate data-getting from html.

Comment: @BuyNaural you returns an array so in your callback you must specified index 0 `data[0]['column'];` also add `limit 1` into your query to optimize it.

Comment: var id = data[0]['Id']; returns undefined

Comment: can you `console.log(data);` see whats the result or also `console.log(typeof data);` see if it's result converted as json object

Comment: console log returns all of my html followed by [{"Id":"8","email":"test@gmail.com"}]  and type of returns a string

Comment: I see, can you screen shot it I want to see it :D

Comment: try changing it to `json_encode( $result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );`

Comment: still returns the html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't passed properly your `$_GET` parameter

To solve that

Change your

```
url: 'dead.php'
```

to

```
url: 'dead.php?id=8',
```

also `data: your_data` is no longer needed

Or this method change

```
data: "id=8"
```

to

```
data: {id: 8}
```

Also in your callback since your ajax response returns an array specified the index `0`

```
success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var id = data[0]['Id'];              //get id
    var vname = data[0]['name'];           //get name
    alert("a"); 
  }
```

Comment: maybe add `var id = data[0]['id'];` to your answer